# Add (unique)index to properties of Fluent Nhibernate auto mapped classes

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, indexing, automapping

We are using Fluent NHibernate with automapping for our objects.
Something like:

```
AutoPersistenceModel autoMap =
    AutoMap
    .Assemblies(mappingConfig, assembliesToMap.ToArray())
    .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<BaseEntity>();
```

I want to to add some indexes to some properties of my objects

I suspect that it can be done somewhere in the mappingConfig object, but I have no idea how this should be done!

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to use overrides to do this:

http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Altering_entities

```
.Override<Shelf>(map =>
{
  map.Map(x => x.SomeProperty)
     .Index("ix_myIndex");
});
```